# Specify MIME type to CUPS's lpr command

Tags: command-line, printing, cups

It seems when you pass a file to `lpr` (or pipe to it), it attempts to guess the MIME type. Sometimes, however, it guesses wrong—and then attempts to print something "interesting" at best.

Is there a way to manually override the MIME type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MIME type is sent in the IPP attribute `document-format`, which you can specify with the `-o` option:

```
lpr -o document-format=text/plain ...
```

Note that if you try a document format that your CUPS server doesn't support, you'll get an error:

```
$ lpr -o document-format=image/svg+xml drawing.svg 
lpr: Unsupported document-format "image/svg+xml".
```

That error is actually coming back from the server.